# CMake Link to External Library without Package finder

Tags: linker, makefile, cmake

I have a precompiled library that I have to make visible to my Cmake project, and I don't understand how I would use the package finder in Cmake to find that library. The external library itself has nothing to do with CMake. Anyone have any suggestions?

Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few days later, I post; What ended up working for me was:

```
link_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/ext/lib")
```

Where ext/lib has external precompiled libraries. I didn't want to link just to a specific target.

Answer (score 2):

```
include_directories(path/to/my/library/headers)
target_link_libraries(myTarget path/to/my/library.so|.dll)
```

Comment: I didn't want to link to a specific target.